# how to display part of text in qcombobox (QT)

Tags: qt, qcombobox

My understanding is the current display text is related to the qcombobox itemlist content.If one item length is very long and wider than qcombobox's width.how to just display part of the text on the qcombobox?

[image]

seen from the above picture, QT already displays part of the text(the full item is ending with 'ker', the display item is ending with 'sdl') but can I control the exact display text? because my combobox has a background image and the arrow will be more left than the that in the above picture .

Another question is can I control the item text display in dropdown window as well? QT replaces some words with '...' but I like to control it myself.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
m_combobox->addItem("a very long long long long long long text ");
    QFont font("times", 24);
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    QString elidedText= fm.elidedText("a very long long long long long long text ",Qt::ElideRight, 80);
m_combobox->addItem(elidedText);
```

you can make a function that takes a QString as parameter and return a QString you give it your text and it return the elided text.

Answer (score 1):

you can store an arbitrary substring as items text and the whole string in userData:

in pyqt:

```
for text in itemlist:
        combobox.addItem(text[0:n], text)
```

and get the displaytext, userData by:

```
combobox.currentText()
combobox.currentData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```

or by

```
combobox.itemText(index)
combobox.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```